# I want to create a thigh stocking tightening scene

Tags: modifiers, physics

[image][image][image]

This is the scene I have created so far, consisting of legs and stockings, and the modifier composition of the two objects.

It's a slightly ignorant structure, but because we had in mind the stocking-removing scene, we excluded items that only work in certain areas, such as surface deform or jiggle maker plug-in.

It works well, but the stockings don't get bumped one way and cause tightness in the thighs.

[image]

to

[image]

I was able to see the difference, and when the Armature was stopped, the skin tightened as intended.

But when I play the animation...

[image]

In this way, the collisions become entangled and create bizarre movements.

Since the stockings deform only after receiving a collision, it is presumed that the leg that moves first is damaged by the collision of the stocking. I tried adjusting the pin group parameters or lightening the vertex mass, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

It might be resolved by prioritizing conflicts, but I haven't found a way to do it. And if there is no friction between the legs in stockings, tightness will not occur, so it is meaningless.

Can I get help solving this problem?